# View Objects don't connect to the File's Owner

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I am trying to "Connect" my objects in the view to the `File's Owner` using the `interface builder`, but the blue line does not 'link' with it. Here is my code:

`CalculatorViewController.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@interface CalculatorViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *display;
    IBOutlet UIButton *button;
    CalculatorBrain *brain;
    BOOL userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber;
}

- (IBAction)digitPressed: (UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)operationPressed: (UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

`CalculatorViewController.m`:

```
#import "CalculatorViewController.h"

@implementation CalculatorViewController

- (CalculatorBrain *)brain
{
    if (!brain) {
        brain = [[CalculatorBrain alloc] init];
    }
    return brain;
}


- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *digit = [[sender titleLabel] text];
    if (userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber) {
        [display setText: [[display text] stringByAppendingString:digit]];
    } else {
        [display setText:digit];
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = YES;
    }
}

- (IBAction)operationPressed: (UIButton *)sender 
{
    if (userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber) {
        [[self brain] setOperand: [[display text] doubleValue]];
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = NO;
    }
    NSString *operation = [[sender titleLabel] text];
    double result = [[self brain] performOperation:operation];
    [display setText: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%g", result]];
}
@end
```

Comment: Give iboutlet to object . like this IBOutlet UITextField *txtPassword; then see interface builder

Comment: Please include the CalculatorViewController.h contents instead/also

Comment: @user681410: Please check out my answer. I have edited my answer and put a screenshot of what exactly you need to look for. Hope that helps you.

Comment: Code has been edited to add "IBOutlet UIButton *button" in the header file.

Comment: -1 for you. I think you should also look into the **time at which the answer is given** by answerers and tick your answer based on that. Because the quicker the solution better it is for you.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you watching the Stanford class on Objective-C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have made sure the File's Owner is set to be CalculatorViewController, make sure that the IBOutlet type in the CalculatorViewController.h file matches the UI component type you are trying to connect it to. Your header defines an IBOutlet for a UILabel, which means only a UILabel can be connected to it.
If the component is of a different type, lets say a UIButton, then you would change your header file to include an IBOutlet like so:

```
IBOutlet UIButton *button;
```

Once you have defined the UIButton in your header, switch to IB. Double check that file's owner is set to your viewcontroller class, then add a UIButton to the view. Then you should be able to either:

1. ctrl+drag from the component to the file's owner
2. right-click on the file's owner and get a HUD styled popup showing all available IBOutlet's. click and drag from the UIButton one to the UIButton in your view.

If you want the UIButton in IB to trigger one of your defined IBActions, you will make a connection to the action. I usually perform this by right-clicking on the File's Owner, which will show all available IBActions and IBOutlets.

[image: Making connection from UIButton to IBAction]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, I added the IBOutlet for UIButton, but it still doesn't work. Do I need to use the pointer to its object somewhere?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "pointer to its object", but added some details to my answer.

Comment: When I write
IBOutlet UIButton *button;
then button is the pointer to the UIButton object, right? 
So, do I need to use 'button' somewhere in my class?

Comment: The ctrl+drag fails.
When I right click on the File's Owner, this is what I see

Outlet
searchDisplayController     
view

Referencing Outlet
New Referencing Outlet

Comment: sounds like either: 1. you haven't saved the .h file in XCode (which causes IB not to see the changes); or 2. the File's Owner is not set to the right class.

Comment: Tried both, still the same problem. I tried reloading the classes even. Still no solution. Anything else you can think of that might cause this problem?

Comment: My only other suggestion would be that your xcode installation has gotten corrupted somehow. Perhaps a "sledgehammer" solution, but maybe you should try a re-install of xcode and ib?

Answer (score 9):

Try and check if class of your File's Owner is set to your ViewController Class properly in your XIB.

For checking Go to your XIB

Click on File's Owner and Open the Inspector.

In inspector, go to the last(fourth) tab and check whether you have set your class as `<yourViewControllerName>`

Hope this helps you.

**EDIT:**

For better understanding I have added an image of where you need to look for the class.

[image]

Also please cross check that you have declared the variables with `IBOutlet` Prefix in your ViewController's header file

Comment: Nope, that's not the problem. The class was already CalculatorViewController. :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the file owner(in interface builder) to the class CalculatorViewController.

Comment: yeah, the class is set to CalculatorViewController. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Im no expert on Interface Builder or Objective C, but did you use:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *yourButton;
```

and then in the .m file:

```
@synthesize yourButton;
```

Im also not sure, but you may have to 'build' it first, then
go into Interface Builder and then it may 'connect' up.